# CakePHP 2.10の環境でSearchPluginを取り入れて実行したらエラー

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP 2.10の環境でSearchPluginを取り入れてコントローラを実行したら下記のエラーが出ます。

```
Error: Unsupported operand types File: C:\省略\lib\Cake\Core\CakePlugin.php Line: 101
```

https://github.com/CakeDC/search/tree/master
からプラグインを落として取り込んだのですが落としてくるものが間違っているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP 2.x の最新版であれば、エラー該当行は [/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php#L101](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/da8414e13bfc559f1eb7c45176050a2c1a16562b/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php#L101) で、 `$config` に対して配列のマージを行っています。
Unsupported operand typesのエラーが出ているということは、 `CakePlugin::load()` の第2引数 `$config` に配列以外の値が代入されている可能性が高いです。

bootstarp.php等で、 `CakePlugin::load()` を呼び出している箇所を確認し、第2引数に配列以外の値をセットしていないか確認してください。